# Unable to call methods of nested Child component from Parent Component in LWC

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning, lightning-web-components

In my parent component I am calling a child component like below:

parentCmp

```
<template>
    <lightning-tab>...</lightning-tab>
    <lightning-tab>...</lightning-tab>
    <lightning-tab label="Child Component">
         <c-child-component param={childParam}></c-child-component>
    </lightning-tab>
</template>
```

In order to call the methods of child Component from parent, I am doing the below steps:

parentCmp.js

```
callChild(){
   this.template.querySelector("c-child-component").connectedCallback();
}
```

Since, the `<c-child-component param={childParam}></c-child-component>` in parent Component is called inside `<lightning-tab>` tag, so I am getting the error `cannot read connectedCallback() of undefined`. Is there any direct way to call the methods of child component which are nested in some other tags?

Comment: It makes no sense for the parent code to call the standard LWC lifecycle methods. This will happen automatically and at the appropriate point. See the [documentation](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/documentation/en/lwc/create_javascript_methods) about how to call child methods and note that you need to wait until the children are actually created before trying to interact with them.

Comment: But is there any way to call child methods before they are rendered?

Comment: By making sure the child doesn't render anything until the parent has called a specific method, by surrounding the whole child template with a ```<template if:true></template>```?

Comment: Okay, but in this case, I have child component inside lightning:tab, so will it be good to wrap lightning:tab also inside if:true?